# Communication between Clients

Tags: multithreading, wcf, client, communication

I have a very basic WCF SOAP Service that does simple tasks like commiting MYSQL commands sending the reply to the client. 
Now, I want to be able to communicate something like an event inbetween two or more clients. If two clients active their events, I want the server to send them both the same specific information at the same time.

So basically, i am looking for a way to communicate between clients in a server-client based architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is a duplex contract which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184.aspx) (and has code examples) I have not done this myself but this seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Another method would be to publish a method to an esb bus/message queue and have your clients consume that.

Always remember in network communication that latency means you may not receieve this information at exactly the same time... but theres no way around that.